# How do I target a specific element that's using a universal selector?

Tags: css, css-selectors

So, I'm trying to work on the CSS of Google Drive with *Stylus*, an extension used for overriding the CSS of websites locally. Folders are a type of element that are designated a universal selector (jGNTYb). This helped when it came to altering the dimensions of folders, among other things. The problem comes in where I'm trying to assign a background image to act as a thumbnail for specific folders. This is a personal project and it's a small volume of content, so assigning thumbnails individually isn't a problem for me.

The selector changes when the folder is active and becomes unique, but I can't allow folder to be put in a constantly active state because I want to add certain animations to it that I want to only be shown when the folder is in an active state as an element. Because of this, I can't take advantage of the unique selector that's generated when the folder is active. This sucks because, while it is a unique selector, it always seems to be the same for each specific folder.

Is there any way that I could work around this problem? I want to be able to assign folder thumbnails individually, specifically when they're not in an active or hovering state. Sadly, trying to add a background to parent elements and child elements don't encompass the whole background of the folder, nor do they have unique selectors, even when in an active or hovering state. Trying to use :nth-child() didn't work, either.

Comment: Need at least some HTML with CSS, otherwise we have to guess or ask questions on every aspect of your problem, see how to post a [mcve].